# If $T= T_1 \cup T_2$ is inconsistent, then can we conclude that $T_1 \models \neg \phi$ for some $\phi\in T_2$

Tags: logic, model-theory

I have seen this reasoning elsewhere and I am not sure wether it is correct.

I think the reasoning behind it should be as follows: Suppose that T is inconsistent.
Then $T_2$ is inconsistent with $T_1$ and so there is $\phi \in T_2$ such that $T_1 \nvDash \phi$.

But I can't find a proof of why it is the case that $T_2$ is inconsistent with $T_1$, as I only know that they both should be inconsistent by compactness.
Also, we need to know that $T_1$ is complete to deduce to know that $T_1 \models \neg \phi$.

What is missing in this argument?

Comment: What does "$T_2$ is inconsistent with $T_1$" mean to you, if not "$T_1\cup T_2$ is inconsistent"?

Comment: Your assumption is that $T_1 \cup T_2$ is inconsistent. If $T_2$ is inconsistent on its own then so is $T_1 \cup T_2$ automatically, and you have no useful information about $T_1$. spaceisdarkgreen's answer gives a more explicit example of this phenomenon.

Answer (score 8):

Not necessarily. Let $T_1=\emptyset$ and $T_2=\{\phi,\lnot\phi\}$ where neither $\phi$ nor $\lnot \phi$ is valid. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews right, but the OP asked if there is necessarily a formula $\theta\in T_2$ such that $T_1\models\neg\theta$. the answer of spaceisdarkgreen shows that this is not the case in general

Comment: Yeah, okay, that reading makes the question trivial, so I assumed OP meant something more.

Answer (score 3):

The best you can do is get:

$$T_1\models \lnot(P_1\land \cdots \land P_n)$$

For some $P_1,\dots,P_n\in T_2.$

This is true because if there is a proof of $\phi\land\lnot\phi$ in $T_1\cup T_2,$ let $P_1,\dots,P_n$ be the statements from $T_2$ used in the proof.

Then $$T_1\models (P_1\land\cdots \land P_n)\implies (\phi\land\lnot \phi)$$

From which you get, by proof by contradiction:

$$T_1\models \lnot(P_1\land\cdots \land P_n)$$

There is no particular way to decide which of the $P_i$ is the “cause” of the contradiction. It could possibly be true that $T_1\cup T_2\setminus \{P_i\}$ is consistent for each $i.$ So *which* $P_i$ is false is not decidable in $T_1.$

Comment: dear Thomas, you are assuming here that $T_2$ is closed under logical implication; ie that if $T_2\models\theta$ then $\theta\in T_2$. but this is not true in general; even though it is the case that $T_2\models \neg(P_1\wedge\dots\wedge P_n)$, that does not mean that $\neg(P_1\wedge\dots\wedge P_n)\in T_2$.

Comment: In your last line, did you mean to say that the conjunction of the $P_i$ is in $T_1$ (not $T_2$)? Again, this need not be true if $T_1$ is not closed under implication.

Comment: Answer edited to make it make sense in response to the actual question. @AtticusStonestrom

Comment: @ThomasAndrews nice! :) (+1) I think it's good to have that info for OP on top of the other answer

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $T=T_1 \cup T_2$ is inconsistent, and $T, T_1, T_2 \neq \emptyset$ then by compactness, it is not the case that every finite subset of T is consistent.

As $T_1, T_2 \subseteq T$, w.l.o.g suppose that there is M such that $M \models T_1$, then $M \nvDash T_2$ so there is some $\phi \in T_2$ such that $T_1 \nvDash \phi$.

If additionally $T_1$ is complete: $T_1 \models \neg \phi$.